# How to fetch status of javascript and css requests from network in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, http-headers

I want to fetch the status of specific JavaScript and CSS network requests of my website https://lifesciences.cactusglobal.com. These network requests can be seen in chrome network. I want to print the request URL and its response code. Screenshot attached below for reference, check the underlined requests: 
[image]

I tried using the package `selenium-wire`

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

But it returns only responses and headers of the URL entered and not the network requests. Is there any other way to traverse through the network requests in selenium python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your support. I found a solution which suits my requirement well.
Referred to these links:
https://gist.github.com/rengler33/f8b9d3f26a518c08a414f6f86109863c
https://www.rkengler.com/how-to-capture-network-traffic-when-scraping-with-selenium-and-python/

Also found a package as an easy way out (not sticking to it though) - `pip install selenium-wire`

Answer (score 1):

The output is a mess, but try getting the network requests like this, it seemed to work for me:

```
driver.get('https://lifesciences.cactusglobal.com/')
time.sleep(3)
test = driver.execute_script("var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;")

for item in test:
  print(item)
```

Comment: Many thanks @C. Peck. Your solution did work but I found another patch which suits more to my requirement. Adding those in the comments